# Poor performance in Metal drawing app when render more than 4000 strokes

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I'm creating a drawing app with Metal. Unlike other drawing app, my app stores all strokes as data model rather than just saving the bitmap result after drawing, the goal of this approach is allowing users to use eraser tool and remove a stroke without touching other strokes.
When user erase a stroke, the app have to render remaining strokes on the screen again, so the function to render all strokes on the screen should be as fast as possible, but I'm having problem with it.

The data model is an array of strokes. Each stroke contains an array of CGPoint captured by touches (red color):
[image: Points captured by gesture]
When render a stroke, I calculate and cache the points along the path (violet color) then I use the same texture and stamp it on each violet points.
A drawing could have more than 4000 strokes and each stroke have ~150 violet points, that's alot but I believe Metal could handle it.

When render strokes on the screen, I use this function:

```
func renderAllStrokes(strokes: [Stroke]) {
    renderer.updateUniFormBuffer()
    renderer.updateTransformBuffer()
    renderer.clear()

    for stroke in strokes {
        self.renderStroke(stroke: stroke)
    }

    renderer.commitCommandBufer()
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

and this function to render each stroke:

```
func renderStroke(stroke: Stroke) {
    // Need to use cached points along path to stamp textures in same distance
    let pointsAlongPath = stroke.cachedPointsAlongPath

    let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()
    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderer.renderPassDescriptor)
    commandEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)

    let pointsAlongPathBuffer = sharedDevice?.makeBuffer(bytes: pointsAlongPath, length: MemoryLayout<MetalStrokePoint>.stride * pointsAlongPath.count, options: .cpuCacheModeWriteCombined)

    if let pointsAlongPathBuffer {
        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(pointsAlongPathBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(renderer.uniformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(renderer.transformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 2)
    
        commandEncoder?.setFragmentTexture(self.stampTexture, index: 0)
    
        commandEncoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: pointsAlongPath.count)
    }

    renderer?.commitCommandBufer()
}
```

The pointsAlongPath (violet points) are cached so I don't have to recalculate when render it again on the screen. But when I redraw the strokes again on the screen, it takes 2 seconds for 4000 strokes and make my app not responsive. The CPU usage is 130% during the time.

The profiler says 26% of the CPU usage is from

```
commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()
```

and 9% from

```
sharedDevice?.makeBuffer(bytes: pointsAlongPath, length: MemoryLayout<MetalStrokePoint>.stride * pointsAlongPath.count, options: .cpuCacheModeWriteCombined)
```

It seems like one of the problems is creating CommandBuffer for each stroke is too often, but according to Apple, the CommandBuffer should be cheap to create.
I don't know if it is possible and if it helps, using the same CommandBuffer for all strokes, because each stroke could use different texture and the app support overall more than 10 textures for each brush.

I've though about instanced rendering, but I think it won't help, because I have already reused uniformBuffer, transformBuffer and stampTexture (I'm not sure).

I would be grateful if someone could help me to point out where the problem are and give me suggestions.

---

First update: After following the suggestions, I have encoded all 4000 strokes into a single commandBuffer:

```
func renderStroke(strokes: [Stroke]) {
    let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()
    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderer.renderPassDescriptor)
    commandEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)

    var allPoints = [MetalStrokePoint]()

    for stroke in strokes {
        let pointsAlongPath = stroke.cachedPointsAlongPath
        allPoints.append(contentsOf: pointsAlongPath)
    }

    let pointsAlongPathBuffer = sharedDevice?.makeBuffer(bytes: allPoints, length: MemoryLayout<MetalStrokePoint>.stride * allPoints.count, options: .cpuCacheModeWriteCombined)

    if let pointsAlongPathBuffer {
        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(pointsAlongPathBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(renderer.uniformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(renderer.transformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 2)

        commandEncoder?.setFragmentTexture(self.stampTexture, index: 0)

        commandEncoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: pointsAlongPath.count)
    }

    renderer?.commitCommandBufer()
}
```

Now there is only 1 draw call for 4000 strokes. When I make a loop with CADisplayLink to render all strokes on the screen, it increased the FPS of my app from 2 FPS to 12 FPS - that's quite impressive but still below my goal. To render 4000 strokes, I have to render 1 million vertexes in draw call. **Is it possible to reach 60 or even 120 FPS?**

I will try indirect rendering and instancing then update the question again, Many thanks to the suggestions, that's very helpful <3

---

After implement triple ring buffers to avoid creating buffer for every drawing call. It do not change the FPS of my app, only reduce 5% of the CPU usage. Am I missing something?

```
func renderStroke(strokes: [Stroke]) {
    let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()
    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderer.renderPassDescriptor)
    commandEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)

    var allPoints = [MetalStrokePoint]()

    for stroke in strokes {
        let pointsAlongPath = stroke.cachedPointsAlongPath
        allPoints.append(contentsOf: pointsAlongPath)
    }

    // NEW: Reuse ring buffer to avoid creating new buffer
    let ringBuffer = renderer.ringBuffers.getCurrentRingBuffer()

    let ringBufferContents = ringBuffer.contents().bindMemory(to: MetalStrokePoint.self, capacity: allPoints.count)

    for (pointIndex, point) in allPoints.enumerated() {
        ringBufferContents[pointIndex] = point
    }

        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(ringBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(renderer.uniformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(renderer.transformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 2)

        commandEncoder?.setFragmentTexture(self.stampTexture, index: 0)

        commandEncoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: pointsAlongPath.count)

        renderer.commandBuffer?.addCompletedHandler({ commandBuffer in
            renderer.ringBufferSemaphore?.signal()
        })

    renderer?.commitCommandBufer()
```

}

Comment: You are creating a command buffer per-stroke, which is not necessary at all. Command buffers may be cheap to create, but each time you create a render command encoder and execute it, it needs to execute it's load and store actions. So if you are drawing your stroke on a 4K texture, lets say, it would need to load and then store 4K texture to device memory, which obviously takes a lot of time and energy

Comment: You don't need to create a new command buffer or a command encoder to change the texture or the data. You can just encode a bunch of draws and it will work much faster than what you have right now.

Comment: I have edited the question. My code now use a single command buffer for all 4000 strokes. It's much faster now but still below my expectation. Do you have any idea to make it faster?

Comment: My other suggestion would be to not allocate an `MTLBuffer` during actual encoding. You can have a ring buffer of pre-allocated buffers that are big enough to hold the data you need to pass. If you don't have a good estimate upfront, you can at least have a "cache" of MTLBuffers that are big enough for a good sized batch of points. Also, instancing seems like a good call here, to be honest. On swift side of things, having an empty `allPoints` `Array` that you append to in a for loop is going to get you a lot of copying to grow array. Try calling `reserveCapacity` on the array before the loop.

Comment: I'm implementing ring buffers, I created 3 buffers and reuse them. It costed quite a lot of time for me to implement it because the only source I found is from an old article from Apple written in ObjC. It's almost done but I'm still hanging in copying 'allPoints' data to the existing buffer. 
I can create a new buffer with 'allPoints' by 'device.makeBuffer(bytes: length:)' but I don't know how to write the data to exisiting buffer. Could you please invite me to a room and help me to implement it? I would happy to pay for your time to help.

Comment: Just just updated the question for triple buffers, it do not change the FPS nor CPU usage, is the implement correct?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here that number of draw calls (`commandEncoder?.drawPrimitives`) is linear from number of strokes. Typically, rendering engines minimize number of draw calls to achieve the best performance. It's relatively expensive operation if it's done on CPU side. Especially if it's accompanied by changing pipeline's states or resources (textures, buffers).

What can be done:

1. **Batching**. You bake strokes in large vertex/index buffers and render them using small number of draw calls from CPU.
2. **Indirect rendering**. Here you generate draw calls from GPU, using argument buffers. Metal is quite flexible in that. Please, check the following [examples](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/indirect_command_encoding).
3. **Instancing** can help, even though it's more limited than indirect rendering. It will also allow you to spare some draw calls.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the answer, I have implemented the first solution, now my app only uses one single command buffer for all 4000 strokes. It runs much faster but still below my expectation (please read the updated question for more details). I wonder if it could get faster.. I'm learning to implement indirect rendering and instancing but I'm not quite understand what you meant with "what can be done": should I implement all 3 of them or should I just pick 1 of the 3 solutions (if they are 3 steps of a solution or 3 solutions)?

Comment: In your case, 1 of 3 should be enough. In complexes renderers, combinations of all them are in use. 
I suppose, you can make it faster. I'd recommend to get rid of creation of large buffer every frame. Please, check comment above about circular buffer.

Comment: I'm implementing ring buffers, I created 3 buffers and reuse them. It's almost done but I'm still hanging in copying 'allPoints' data to the existing buffer. I can create a new buffer with 'allPoints' by 'device.makeBuffer(bytes: length:)' but I don't know how to write the data to exisiting buffer. Could you please invite me to a room and help me to implement it? I would happy to pay for your time to help.

Comment: First of all, modifying buffers is quite straightforward, please check [MTLBuffer contents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlbuffer/1515716-contents). It returns pointer that can be use to write, just do not forget to use proper resource options (e.g. `storageModeShared`).
After it's just an algorithm not really connected to Metal: write new data to the end of a large buffer, erase data that need to be erased, when you buffer has no more space - reallocate it, copy data from previous buffer with defragmentation, increase space if it's required.