# Triple (ring) buffering doesn't increase the FPS

Tags: swift, metal

I'm creating a drawing app with Metal. Unlike other drawing app, my app stores all strokes as data model rather than just saving the bitmap result after drawing, the goal of this approach is allowing users to use eraser tool and remove a stroke without touching other strokes.
When user erase a stroke, the app have to render remaining strokes on the screen again, so the function to render all strokes on the screen should be as fast as possible, but I'm having problem with it.

When render strokes on the screen, I use this function:

```
    func renderStroke(strokes: [Stroke]) {
        let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()
        let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderer.renderPassDescriptor)
        commandEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)

        var allPoints = [MetalStrokePoint]()
    
        for stroke in strokes {
            let pointsAlongPath = stroke.cachedPointsAlongPath
            allPoints.append(contentsOf: pointsAlongPath)
        }
    
        let pointsAlongPathBuffer = sharedDevice?.makeBuffer(bytes: allPoints, length: MemoryLayout<MetalStrokePoint>.stride * allPoints.count, options: .cpuCacheModeWriteCombined)

        if let pointsAlongPathBuffer {
            commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(pointsAlongPathBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
            commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(renderer.uniformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
            commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(renderer.transformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 2)

            commandEncoder?.setFragmentTexture(self.stampTexture, index: 0)

            commandEncoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: pointsAlongPath.count)
        }

        renderer?.commitCommandBufer()
    }
```

I tested to render 4000 strokes to the screen by calling this function in a CADisplayLink loop, the length of the buffer is 4'000'000 (Is that too much for Metal to handle?) and the FPS of the app is 12 FPS - That is way too slow and make my app not responsive.

Then some guys here have suggested not to create a new buffer for each draw call:
[Poor performance in Metal drawing app when render more than 4000 strokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74630753/poor-performance-in-metal-drawing-app-when-render-more-than-4000-strokes).
So I implemented ring buffer to reuse buffer for each draw call:

```
    func renderStroke(strokes: [Stroke]) {
        // Wait for a free ring buffer
        renderer?.ringBufferSemaphore?.wait()

        let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()
        let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderer.renderPassDescriptor)
        commandEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)

        var allPoints = [MetalStrokePoint]()

        for stroke in strokes {
            let pointsAlongPath = stroke.cachedPointsAlongPath
            allPoints.append(contentsOf: pointsAlongPath)
        }

        // Reuse ring buffer to avoid creating new buffer
        let ringBuffer = renderer.ringBuffers.getCurrentRingBuffer()
    
        let ringBufferContents = ringBuffer.contents().bindMemory(to: MetalStrokePoint.self, capacity: allPoints.count)
    
        for (pointIndex, point) in allPoints.enumerated() {
            ringBufferContents[pointIndex] = point
        }

        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(ringBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(renderer.uniformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(renderer.transformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 2)

        commandEncoder?.setFragmentTexture(self.stampTexture, index: 0)

        commandEncoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: pointsAlongPath.count)

        // Signal to free current ring buffer
        renderer.commandBuffer?.addCompletedHandler({ commandBuffer in
            renderer.ringBufferSemaphore?.signal()
        })
    
        renderer?.commitCommandBufer()
    }
```

Result: CPU usage recuced by 5% but the FPS do not change. Am I doing anything wrong here or just ring buffers do not help in this case?

Comment: What is your target device?

Comment: Ipad pro 2018 and ipad pro M1

Comment: Have you tried using GPU instancing?

Comment: Do you mean using:
drawPrimitives(type: MTLPrimitiveType, vertexStart: Int, vertexCount: Int, instanceCount: Int, baseInstance: Int) and set instanceCount to the number of points?

Comment: [Encodes a command](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder/1515327-drawprimitives?language=objc) to render a number of instances of primitives using vertex data in contiguous array elements.

Comment: For instanced rendering, the per-instance-buffer is the ringBuffer (which contains allPoints), is that right? Can that help to render faster, even the ringBuffer still needed to sent to the GPU?

Comment: What type of data is stored in your ring buffer?

Comment: What is the size of your ring buffer in megabytes?

Comment: The data type in the ring buffer is a struct MetalStrokePoint and the size of the ring buffer is 47 MB. MetalStrokePoint contains float4 for position and float4 for color. Could we start a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250098/discussion-between-hamid-yusifli-and-brew-master).

Comment: I'm in the room